# Is there a cleaner way to loop and capture the object ids to a list?

Tags: java

Say I have a collection of users:

```
List<User> users = ...;
```

Now I want to get all the id's for the users in a list, currently I am doing:

```
for(User user : users) {
  userIds.add(user.getId());
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

I know java doesnt' support linq, so maybe this is the only way but just thought I'd ask.

Comment: I think that is about the most elegant you are going to get with java

Comment: Sadly, *no*, not really - Java doesn't support HoF's like `map` :( There are "functional" Java libraries (e.g. FJ), but they can add more boilerplate than it's worth for a simple case like this. ([JDK 8 might finally have good enough support for practical HoFs.](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/))

Comment: `userIds = {user.getID() for (User user : users)}; // wouldn't this be nice`

Comment: Nope, this is as good as it gets in Java as far as coding elegance and efficiency.

Comment: check guava  Lists.transform()

Comment: @Wug That's not valid in Java.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: yeah, that's why it would be nice.

Comment: @Wug It's disgruntling to realize that Perl, Ruby, Scala, C#, JS, ST (to name just a few) all support this "would be nice" approach .. I have given up on Java as a language.

Comment: @pst: You can even abuse C++ into doing it with templates.

Comment: @Wug There is no need to use templates. Even a "non-closure" function-pointer (e.g. old C) would be sufficient. Of course C++ (and C via extensions?) now both support various forms of closures as well .. (but a closure isn't even required here)

Answer (score 2):

with Google Guava Collections2

elegant ?

```
        Collections2.transform(lists, new Function<User, UserId>(){
            public UserId apply(@Nullable User user) {
                return user.getId();
            }

        });
```

Comment: +1 Because it shows a "map" function; the approach in FJ would be similar (manual creation of an anonymous Function class/instance). However, no, it's not "elegant" - the fundamental problem is the Java syntax simply lacks the required mechanisms to avoid the boilerplate. (Scala, another statically-typed JVM language, has syntax that takes care of the boilerplate. JDK 8 might have similar nicety support as well.)

Comment: However, one thing to note is that `new Function ..` just returns an instance with a specific nominative chain/interface. It can be promoted into a named type, e.g. `class UserToIdMap extends Function .. transform(lists, new UserToIdMap())`.

Comment: I wouldn't call that elegant hahaha, but it is def. something interesting to know about.  under the covers is that some sort of a callback per iteration?

Comment: I would not call this elegant. But that is Javas fault ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. Only other thing I would suggest is to add `Null Check` and `Empty Check (optional)` on `users` and `userIds`.

Comment: No point in an empty check, that will just make the loop run zero times.  Also, I like to reduce such snippets to one liners of the form: `for(User user : users) userIds.add(user.getId());`

Comment: If you know you list `users` is not Empty(or you can ignore as you said) and `userIds` is not null(otherwise this should be handled), I think that fine. Are you looking for anything more?

Comment: I agree with yogendra.. If you are not sure, like 100% sure.than add null checks.. They are highly advisable.